# ntpq -pn broadcast is stratum 16

Tags: ntp

I am working on a project, in which I set up a Raspberry Pi Model 4B as NTP-Server, where the Pi is using an USB GPS to get the correct time. This works fine! Now I want the Server to broadcast the correct time to everyone in the network. Currently its only one member, another Raspberry Pi Model 4B.

When I type

```
ntpq -pn
```

I get a list with actions. One of them is

```
remote            refid     st t  when poll reach delay  offset jitter
192.168.1.255    .BCST.     16 B   -   64   0     0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
```

`st` stands for stratum and 16 means unreachable. How can a broadcast be unreachable?
I dont know how to get this working, does anybody work with ntp and can help me?

After a reboot it looks like this:

```
 remote            refid     st t  when poll reach delay  offset jitter
192.168.1.255    .XFAC.     16 B   -   64   0     0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
```

What does XFAC mean?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

A network interface change/disconnection, or a cleared (i.e. reset) association.

---

Apparently, `XFAC` stands for

- `X` Inter
- `F` Face
- `A` Association
- `C` Change

From [XFAC (?)](https://comp.protocols.time.ntp.narkive.com/N6myvyxK/xfac):

> ntpd resets associations when the local network interface (or, really,
> IP address) being used for that peer goes away. This means the clock
> filter register of 8 samples is cleared, as are all other timekeeping
> stats related to the peer. At that time, the "reference ID" or refid
> is changed to XFAC to indicate the cause of the cleared (reset)
> association. Typically, that XFAC refid is replaced on receipt of the next packet from the server or peer.

A little further down that thread, the same poster also posits that it *might* also mean:

> ... Perhaps eXchange interFACe? ...

However, from [NTP REFID Specification](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/info/ntp-refid.htm):

```
Reference ID (refid): 32-bit code identifying the particular server
or reference clock.  The interpretation depends on the value in the
stratum field.  For packet stratum 0 (unspecified or invalid), this
is a four-character ASCII [RFC1345] string, called the "kiss code",
used for debugging and monitoring purposes.  For stratum 1 (reference
clock), this is a four-octet, left-justified, zero-padded ASCII
string assigned to the reference clock.  The authoritative list of
Reference Identifiers is maintained by IANA; however, any string
beginning with the ASCII character "X" is reserved for unregistered
experimentation and development.  The identifiers in Figure 12 have
been used as ASCII identifiers:


+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| ID   | Clock Source                                             |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| GOES | Geosynchronous Orbit Environment Satellite               |
| GPS  | Global Position System                                   |
| GAL  | Galileo Positioning System                               |
| PPS  | Generic pulse-per-second                                 |
| IRIG | Inter-Range Instrumentation Group                        |
| WWVB | LF Radio WWVB Ft. Collins, CO 60 kHz                     |
| DCF  | LF Radio DCF77 Mainflingen, DE 77.5 kHz                  |
| HBG  | LF Radio HBG Prangins, HB 75 kHz                         |
| MSF  | LF Radio MSF Anthorn, UK 60 kHz                          |
| JJY  | LF Radio JJY Fukushima, JP 40 kHz, Saga, JP 60 kHz       |
| LORC | MF Radio LORAN C station, 100 kHz                        |
| TDF  | MF Radio Allouis, FR 162 kHz                             |
| CHU  | HF Radio CHU Ottawa, Ontario                             |
| WWV  | HF Radio WWV Ft. Collins, CO                             |
| WWVH | HF Radio WWVH Kauai, HI                                  |
| NIST | NIST telephone modem                                     |
| ACTS | NIST telephone modem                                     |
| USNO | USNO telephone modem                                     |
| PTB  | European telephone modem                                 |
+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, the initial `X` seems to mean that is it experimental:

> However, any string
> beginning with the ASCII character "X" is reserved for unregistered
> experimentation and development.

Nevertheless, the [Wikipedia entry for NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) states

> The program output may additionally use codes not transmitted in the packet to indicate error, such as XFAC to indicate a network disconnection